# git deployment method leaves me on wrong branch

Tags: git, bash

I was happily getting used to the git workflow I had set up (or is that "gitting" used to it?), when I ran into a little snag just now.  I have a dev directory and a codebase directory (my live code), and the git repo is in the dev directory.  I have a bash alias for when I want to deploy the current code of the master branch:

```
alias deploy='cd /my/path/codebase; git --git-dir=/my/path/dev/.git --work-tree=/my/path/codebase checkout -f master; cd -'
```

It works fine as long as HEAD is on the master branch.  But just now I was working in another branch called texlabels but needed to fix a little bug in master.  So I made sure everything was committed, checked out master, fixed the bug, committed the fix, and then switched back to the texlabels branch before remembering to deploy.  "No problem," I thought, "the alias explicitly asks for the master branch."  True, my codebase directory got exactly what it should have.  But now my dev directory is out of sync with git - the files match the texlabels branch, but HEAD is on master.

Since I knew everything was safely committed, I tried doing another "git checkout texlabels", but as you git gurus probably already know, git folded its arms in protest:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>
> ...files...
>
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>
> Aborting

Hmph!  I guess I can copy the differing files manually from codebase to dev just so I can checkout texlabels again, but that seems silly.  And the bigger question is: What can I add to my bash alias for the future, so that this doesn't happen again?  Yeah, I should remember to deploy right after committing, but I would like to idiot-proof my alias a bit.  Is there a way to determine where HEAD is and store that in a shell variable before doing the stuff I have now, and then afterwards putting HEAD back to where it was?  Or a way to get the files for the codebase directory without moving HEAD at all?  It would be nice if the alias could just retrieve the files of the last master commit, without having any net change in the repo pointers, the index, or my dev directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash your changes, change the branch, and re-apply the stash:

```
git stash
git checkout texlabels
git stash apply
```

To improve your script, I think you can do:

```
git archive master | tar x -C"/my/path/codebase"
```

This copies the content of the master branch.

Comment: Sweet!  I had already fixed my immediate problem (I didn't realize that "stash" was a technical term, so I did it differently), but your script idea works like a charm!